# How to specify day and month for messy date data with missing day and month when converting to date in large data frame

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a large date frame of over 100k rows. The date column contains dates in multiple formats such as `"%m/%d/%Y"`, `"%Y-%m"`, `"%Y"`, and `"%Y-%m-%d"`. I can convert these all to dates with `parse_date_time()` from `lubridate`.

```
dates <- c("05/10/1983","8/17/2014","1953-12","1975","2001-06-17")

parse_date_time(dates, orders = c("%m/%d/%Y","%Y-%m","%Y","%Y-%m-%d"))

[1] "1983-05-10 UTC" "2014-08-17 UTC" "1953-12-01 UTC" "1975-01-01 UTC" "2001-06-17 UTC"
```

But as you can see, this sets dates with missing day to the first of the month and dates with missing month and day to the first of the year. How can I set those to the 15th and June 15th, respectively?

Comment: Looking at the number of characters with `nchar` seems good. If `nchar(dates) == 4`, paste on `"-06-15"`. Then if `nchar < 8` paste on `"-15"`. And maybe do a quick `gsub` to replace all `/` with `-` to get a slightly more uniform format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nchar` to check the dates vector and `paste` what is missing.

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("05/10/1983","8/17/2014","1953-12","1975","2001-06-17")


dates <- ifelse(nchar(dates) == 4, paste(dates, "06-15", sep = "-"),
             ifelse(nchar(dates) == 7, paste(dates, 15, sep = "-"), dates))
dates
#[1] "05/10/1983" "8/17/2014"  "1953-12-15" "1975-06-15"
#[5] "2001-06-17"

parse_date_time(dates, orders = c("%m/%d/%Y","%Y-%m","%Y","%Y-%m-%d"))
#[1] "1983-05-10 UTC" "2014-08-17 UTC" "1953-12-15 UTC"
#[4] "1975-06-15 UTC" "2001-06-17 UTC"
```

Another solution would be to use an index vector, also based on `nchar`.

```
n <- nchar(dates)
dates[n == 4] <- paste(dates[n == 4], "06-15", sep = "-")
dates[n == 7] <- paste(dates[n == 7], "15", sep = "-")

dates
#[1] "05/10/1983" "8/17/2014"  "1953-12-15" "1975-06-15"
#[5] "2001-06-17"
```

As you can see, the result is the same as with `ifelse`.

Comment: after the `nchar()` replacement step, should the replaced formats be removed? It seems like they are just ignored anyway.

Comment: @user29609 Are you talking about the second solution? It still needs `parse_date_time` on the result. If you want to keep the original vector, assign to a different vector `dates2 <- dates` then transform this one.

Comment: No, sorry. I mean the formats specified in the `order` argument that are no longer needed such as `%Y` and `%Y-%m`

Comment: @user29609 The `orders` argument is still needed, you should kep it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing that - based on `orders`:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("05/10/1983","8/17/2014","1953-12","1975","2001-06-17")

parseDates <- function(x, orders = c('mdY', 'dmY', 'Ymd', 'Y', 'Ym')){
  fmts <- guess_formats(x, orders = orders)
  dte <- parse_date_time(x, orders = fmts[1], tz = 'UTC')
  if(!grepl('m', fmts[1]) ){
    dte <- dte + days(165)
    return(dte)
  }
  if(!grepl('d', fmts[1]) ){
    dte <- dte + days(14)
  }
  return(dte)
}
```

**output**

```
> parseDates(dates[4])
[1] "1975-06-15 UTC"
> parseDates(dates[3])
[1] "1953-12-15 UTC"
```

This way for different date formats you only need to change the `orders` argument while the rest is done using `lubridate`.

Hope this is helpful!